# bcp out not leading zeros for numeric

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am exporting some data from SQL Server using bcp out and when the export is finish my numeric fields are droping the 0 before the decimal point.

Here is my code:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell
    'bcp Table  out C:\Temp\Table.csv  -c -C65001 -t\t -r0x0a ';
```

And this is how my numeric looks like: .00

Anyone has ever encounter this problem?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: In what context is this a problem? `.00` is a valid numeric number in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a `BCP OUT`, do a `BCP QUERYOUT` with a query that selects the data in the format you want.

In that query, you can use the SQL Server [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function to format numeric data any way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have more than 200 columns where about 50 to 60 are numeric, in do not not find any other way i will do it your way :)